# how to run my python code on google cloud without fear of getting disconnected - an absolute beginner?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have been trying to use python 3 for text mining on a 650 MB csv file, which my computer was not powerful enough to do. My second solution was to reach out to google cloud. I have set up my VMs and my jupyter notebook on google cloud, and it works perfectly well. The problem, however, is that I am in constant fear of getting disconnected. As a matter of fact, my connection with google server was lost a couple of time and so was my whole work.

My question: Is there a way to have the cloud run my code without fear of getting disconnected? I need to be able to have access to my csv file and also the output file.

I know there is more than one way to do this and have read a lot of material. However, they are too technical for a beginner like me to understand. I really appreciate a more dummy-friendly version. Thanks!

UPDATE: here is how I get access to my jupyter notebook on google cloud:

1- I run my instance on google cloud

2- I click on SSH

3- in the window that appears, I type the following:

`jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --no-browser &`

I have seen people recommend to add `nohup` to the beginning of the same commend. I have tried it and got this message:

`nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'`

And nothing happens.

Comment: maybe you could run program in background (&) or using command `nohup` ("no hang up") and disconnect and it should still run. If you write result in file then next time you should see new data in file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have seen nohup, but don't know when I should use it. should I use it when I want to have access to jupyter notebook? or should  I use it after I launched jupyter notebook?

Comment: instead of `jupyter notebook` you run `nohup jupyter notebook` or maybe even `nohup jupyter notebook &`.

Comment: it is standard message for nohup. It has to do something with input and output when you disconnect and there will be no screen and keyboard. It redirect output from screen to `output.txt`. To test `nohup` you would have to run code, check if it is running - you can use `ps` or `ps aux` - disconnect and connect back and use `ps` again to check if it is still running.

Comment: using `screen` (or [tmux](https://devhints.io/tmux)) can be easier and more interesting then `hup` because with `screen` you can run many terminals (screens) at the same time so you can run many program in separated screens and switch them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you could just run the program inside a screen instance:

After connecting via ssh type `screen`
Run your command
Press ctrl + a, ctrl + d
Now you can disconnect from ssh and your code will continue to run. You can reconnect to the screen via `screen -r`